# split in crystal report

Tags: split, crystal-reports-xi

I have been using Crystal Reports for few weeks and I've encountered a problem.  I have a field that has values like: `2220006989`.  I want to split these number, so that I can arrange each in different column like:

```
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 9 | 8 | 9 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind creating 9 formulas each corresponding to one number ?
each formula would be

```
Mid({ConsideredField},1,1)
Mid({ConsideredField},2,1)
Mid({ConsideredField},3,1)
```

and so on

You would then be able to call them as separate columns (each formula being a column)